# Android disambiguation dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I develop an assistant app with voice commands. In some cases i want the user say or select from disambiguation dialog. Is there any way to select programmatically an item from disambiguation dialog(not custom dialog).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The 'disambiguation dialog' is actually what is called a 'Bottom Sheet' and it is a custom view inside of the support and design lib. You can create whatever you want actually.

Here is a medium post on a nice way to do it.
https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066

Here is a android hive post that is also awesome.
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/